# Extract Sub-Directory Path from Partially Known Directory

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression, string, search

Lets say I've got the following directory structure:

```
base/
|
+-- app
|   |
|   +-- main
|       |
|       +-- sub
|           |
|           +-- first
|           |   |
|           |   +-- tib1.ear
|           |   \-- tib1.xml
|           |
|           \-- second
|               |
|               +-- tib2.ear
|               \-- tib2.xml
```

One of the relative paths to an `ear` file would be `base/app/main/sub/first/tib1.ear`, how could I extract the substrings for:

- The file, `tib1.ear` or `tib2.ear`
- The sub-directory after `base/app/` but not including the file,
  that being `main/sub/first` or `main/sub/second`

All of the directory names are dynamically generated, so I don't know them beyond `base/app/`, and therefore cannot simply use the lengths of the known sub-strings and use `cut` to truncate them; but I see how it could be possible once the filenames are known. I just feel like there's an easier way than cutting and joining a bunch of strings based on the length of other results.

I remember seeing some regular expression magic for something similar to this. It dealt with splitting and joining the substrings with backslashes, but sadly, I don't remember how they did it or where I saw it on here to look it up again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with your filename:

```
$ f=base/app/main/sub/first/tib1.ear
```

To extract the base name:

```
$ echo "${f##*/}"
tib1.ear
```

To extract the desired part of the directory name:

```
$ g=${f%/*}; echo "${g#base/app/}"
main/sub/first
```

`${g#base/app/}` and `${f##*/}` are examples of *prefix removal*.  `${f%/*}` is an example of *suffix removal*.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ```
>    ${parameter#word}
>    ${parameter##word}
>           Remove  matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If
>           the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the  expanded
>           value  of  parameter  with the shortest matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>           ``##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each  positional
>           parameter  in  turn,  and  the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted
>           with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and  the  expansion
>           is the resultant list.
>
>    ${parameter%word}
>    ${parameter%%word}
>           Remove  matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If
>           the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is
>           the  expanded  value  of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest matching
>           pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied  to  each
>           positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable sub‐
>           scripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in  turn,  and  the
>           expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

#### Alternatives

You may also want to consider the utilities `basename` and `dirname`:

```
$ basename "$f"
tib1.ear
$ dirname "$f"
base/app/main/sub/first
```

Comment: Thanks John, this was perfect. For those that don't like to read the whole man-page for functions: `${string##substring}` Deletes longest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`. `${string%substring}` Deletes shortest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`. From [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 2):

creating the test files

```
mkdir -p base/app/main/sub/{first,second}
touch base/app/main/sub/first/tib1.{ear,xml}
touch base/app/main/sub/second/tib2.{ear,xml}
```

finding the ear files with bash

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
ear_files=( base/**/*.ear )
printf "%s\n" "${ear_files[@]}"
```

```
base/app/main/sub/first/tib1.ear
base/app/main/sub/second/tib2.ear
```

Iterate over the array and use John1024's answer to extract the necessary info from each path.

```
for f in "${ear_files[@]}"; do ...; done
```